# ValueAnimator to change background color

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to create a screen with a backgroundcolor that keeps changing from red to blue. For some reason it always crashes when i try to instantiate the ValueAnimator. I have no idea what's wrong with my code

Thank you

**Animation class**

```
public BackgroundAnimation(Context context){
    super(context);
    ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(R.anim.animator, "backgroundColor", Color.RED, Color.BLUE);
    colorAnim.setDuration(3000);
    colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    colorAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    colorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
   colorAnim.start();

}
```

**animator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
   <objectAnimator
         android:propertyName="backgroundColor"/>
</set>
```

**Main class**

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    container.addView(new BackgroundAnimation(this));

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="300sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ObjectAnimator to change the background color:

For API >= 21 :

```
ObjectAnimator colorAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(travelersListView.getBackground().mutate(), "tint", mCurrentBackground, mFadeColor);
colorAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
colorAnimator.start();
```

For backward support from API 16 use this:

```
ObjectAnimator colorAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(travelersListView.getBackground().mutate(), "tint", new ArgbEvaluator(), mCurrentBackground, mFadeColor);
colorAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
colorAnimator.start();
```

Comment: what is mCurrentBackground and what is mFadeColor?  please define

Answer (score 2):

There is not id parameter in XML file for LinearLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/container">
```

Comment: This part is working fine. The crash occurs at line

    ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(R.anim.animator, "backgroundColor", Color.RED, Color.BLUE);

Comment: I have no idea how to debug on my phone. I tried commenting out those 6 lines concerning the valueanimator and then the main screen shows fine. When I uncomment said line, it crashes.

Comment: You can't animate `R.anim.animator`, I don't think. What you probably want to do is `ObjectAnimator.ofInt(yourView, "backgroundColor", Color.RED, Color.BLUE)`.

Comment: Although even that won't work, since colors aren't represented in a continuous way like that. You'll get a really weird animation.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.menu);

LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

changeBackground(container, "#F44336", "#2196F3"); //#F44336 : Red , #2196F3 : Blue

}

public void changeBackground(final View view, String color1, String color2) {
    ValueAnimator anim = new ValueAnimator();
    anim.setIntValues(Color.parseColor(color1), Color.parseColor(color2));
    anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

            view.setBackgroundColor((Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });

    anim.setDuration(2000);
    anim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    anim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    anim.start();
}
```

**Try this, Hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

No variant of `ObjectAnimator.ofInt()` takes resource ID as parameter. Please read this for declaring animations in XML.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#declaring-xml